# React CSS philosophy

Tags: reactjs

I'm building my first proper React app and I have a question about theme vs. component CSS: how do you manage it?

I understand and love the idea of keeping a component's appearance tied to the component itself. That makes a great deal of sense to me. But how do you work with more global visual stuff - I'm thinking colours, corners, that kind of thing? It makes sense to me that all that should go in a global stylesheet, but I can't see how that won't lead to splitting component CSS between stylesheets, which I think it's the idea to avoid doing.

I'm a slow thinker - please feel free to explain this as if I'm 6 years old.

Comment: Use a language like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and define variables in a global stylesheet, then import then as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually have common styles folder with variables(LESS/SASS 
), and styles of common components like buttons, inputs etc. Also we have a styles folder for parts of app, like auth app, there we keep styles for components unique to this application part or redefinition common styles.

Buts it's just our structure, and i think it's nice for reuse.